# How to convert this to Doctrine 2 QueryBuilder format?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I would like to write nested query with Doctrine; Sample SQL is like below:

```
SELECT * FROM layer WHERE layer.id NOT IN 
               (SELECT task_id FROM users_tasks WHERE user_id = 1) 
AND parent_id IS NOT NULL AND leaf IS TRUE
```

I have problem converting the **SECOND** `SELECT` statement.

Thanks in advance.

I would like to make it with `createQueryBuilder` not `createQuery`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

try this :

1) create your subquery

```php
$subquery = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('t.id')
    ->from('yourBundle:Task', 't')
    ->innerjoin('t.user','u')
    ->where('u.id = 1')
    ->getDQL();
```

2) after create your query

```php
$query = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
$query->select('l')
      ->from('yourBundle:Layer', 'l')
      ->where($query->expr()->notIn('l.id', $subquery))
      ....;
```

I tested it and it works :)

Comment: I would like the one with `createQueryBuilder`;

Comment: I modify the query (details above)

Comment: had some problems. I get 
Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens at ...

Can you check this code and let me know where I am gong wrong.
https://www.evernote.com/shard/s338/sh/70b0db2c-a1f8-4c82-ac87-8f6b934be18d/4128fff89622337fa80e7f5aa49c26e7

Comment: @RoydonD'Souza subquery doesn't take account to parameter (getDQL) you should pass parameters to the $qb instead

Comment: @a.aitboudad Thanks a lot. Will do that.