# Home to make nested query in Doctrine 2 ?

Tags: doctrine-orm

I would like to make this with Doctrine 2 :

```
SELECT *, 
 (SELECT action FROM operations_history
         WHERE timesheet.id = operations_history.timesheet_id
         ORDER BY operations_history.created DESC 
          LIMIT 1) as status 
FROM timesheet;
```

Any Help? I would like to do it with `createQueryBuilder();` if possible. Thanks.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762586/how-to-convert-this-to-doctrine-2-querybuilder-format).