# Symfony Doctrine, select from subquery with join

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Haven't been able to find a solid solution for this, but I have a mySQL query that I want to translate to Doctrine. It is a select from a subquery with joins and I might have read somewhere that joins are not allowed in subqueries in Doctrine.

Here is the SQL:

`SELECT part, SUM(qty) as qty FROM (SELECT  part, SUM(qty) as qty FROM sub  LEFT JOIN main ON main.id  = main_id WHERE hold != 1 GROUP BY name, part) AS tbl GROUP BY part`

This is what I tried and it is all wrong.

```
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $q = $em->createQuery('v');
    $q2 = $em->createSubQuery()
        ->select('m.part, sum(s.qty) qty')
        ->from('Sub s')
        ->leftJoin('s.main m')
        ->where('s.hold != 1')
        ->groupBy('m.part');

    $q->select('m.part, sum(qty)', $q2->getDQL());
```

One of the first error I got was:

`FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::createSubQuery() in ....Controller.php line 238`

I am pretty sure it isn't just this that I'm doing wrong but it is the first thing that's coming up. So `getManager()` apparently doesn't have a `createSubQuery()` function? What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

There's no method like `createSubQuery()`. Take a look at that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10763358