# Doctrine2 - Nested SELECT statements error using createQueryBuilder - "Invalid parameter number..."

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

**Context:**

I am trying to convert this query

```
Select 
    *
FROM
    phases AS P
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS( SELECT 
            *
        FROM
            rating AS R
        WHERE
            R.phase_id = P.id AND R.user_id = 53)
LIMIT 1
```

into a couple of createQueryBuilder queries using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762586/how-to-convert-this-to-doctrine-2-querybuilder-format) example

I have generated the following code:

```
    $subquery = $em->createQueryBuilder()
                ->select("r.id")
                ->from('AppDemoBundle:Rating', 'r')
                    ->innerjoin('r.user', 'u')
                    ->where('u.id = :_id')
                    ->setParameter('_id', 53)
                ->getDQL();
    $query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
                ->select('p')
                ->from('AppDemoBundle:Phases', 'p');
    $query->andWhere($query->expr()->notIn('p.id', $subquery));

    $phase = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

but I keep getting this error telling that the number of parameters is incorrect.

```
Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\QueryException: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens (uncaught exception) at C:\\wamp\\www\\demo\\vendor\\doctrine\\lib\\Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\QueryException.php line 62
```

**Question:**

I would appreciate any help with this. It's my first time using the createQueryBuilder and I am not sure why this problem is happening. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try using `setParameter` on the outer query instead of the inner one?

Comment: @Maerlyn, Thank you! That worked like a charm. Please post it as an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `setParameter` on the outer query instead of the outer one. Since that's the one you end up running it seems logical.

Comment: Any idea why the query is not working properly and returning all results? Does the logic match the SQL query that I am trying to execute?

Comment: Use the web debug toolbar to see the query actually being executed, there you can see the differences between your original query and the generated one.

Comment: for some reason, my toolbar does not record any of my DB interactions.